# how to test DOM events returned by document.getElementById in angular using jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have below code in my controller.

```
        var myLink = document.getElementById('myId');

        myLink.onclick = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.transitionTo('mystate', { message:"hello" });
        }
```

when I create object for my controller in my test case it is giving the error: **Cannot set property 'onclick' of null**

Anyone know how to handle this?

Comment: entre I know basics. Can you tell how to mock this? If you do not know please do not comment.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ng-click on your element and ditch myLink reference.

```
<div id="myId" ng-click="changeState()"></div>
```

Please read the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the link is not in our control to add ng-click event. It is a part from another project and we can't change the code. But we need to handle this event. Any other solution.

Comment: `spyOn(document, 'getElementById').and.returnValue({});` might do the trick